# Are entangled pairs of fermions, with spin up and spin down, always one matter and the other antimatter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Are entangled pairs of fermions, with spin up and spin down, always one matter and the other antimatter? Or can there be an entangled pair of particles, both ordinary matter, with spin up and spin down? Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily, although this method is most common due to pair production. But in general, entanglement can occur between any two pair of fermions as long as there is a correlation.

Comment: Thank you. So any pair of fermions can have spin up and spin down, and be entangled, without either being antimatter? That was the question.

Comment: Yes they can...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Helium atom. There are two electrons in the $1s$ orbital, and the electrons must have different spin. But they are also identical fermions, so the combined wavefunction must be antisymmetric. Since they are in the same exact spatial orbital, their spin wavefunction is $|\psi\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2} (|\uparrow \downarrow \rangle - |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle)$. This is an entangled state of two electrons (neither being antimatter).